# Format a specific cell with currency rounded format using gspread in python

Tags: gspread, gspread-formatting

I am currently using this

```py
sheet.format("C3:C3", {"numberFormat": {"type": "CURRENCY"}})
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I think that your showing script changes `numberFormat` to `"type": "CURRENCY"`. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand `But it doesn't seem to work`. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: Hey @Tanaike You can see I created an issue [https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1117](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1117)

But here is some code

```py
sheet.update("C3", 6000000)
sheet.format("C3:C3", {"numberFormat": {"type": "CURRENCY"}})
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your link, I proposed a modification point an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

From your following script and `But it doesn't seem to work. Also on the sheet when I click on the cell I see its adding a ' before the number which is only visible on the formula`,

```
sheet.update("C3", 6000000)
sheet.format("C3:C3", {"numberFormat": {"type": "CURRENCY"}})
```

In this case, how about using `value_input_option` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```
sheet.update("C3", 6000000, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
sheet.format("C3:C3", {"numberFormat": {"type": "CURRENCY"}})
```

or

```
sheet.update("C3", 6000000, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
sheet.format("C3", {"numberFormat": {"type": "CURRENCY"}})
```

#### Reference:

- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=update#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)